# Form or get Azure DevOps URL for Release logs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

[image]Using a PowerShell task running as part of this Agent Job, I want to get the URL to link back to the logs (of the same Agent Job).  The URL is consistent but I can't find Predefined variables for releaseID or environmentID which are the missing pieces of the puzzle for the URL.  Does anyone know how to get these IDs or another way of programatically retrieving this URL from a task within the Agent Job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The URL is consistent but I can't find Predefined variables for releaseID or environmentID which are the missing pieces of the puzzle for the URL.

We could check this doc [Default variables - Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release) to get the release predefined variable.

We could also add task **Bash** and enter the script `printenv` to print the variable, then we could see that the `releaseID` is `RELEASE_RELEASEID` or `Release.ReleaseId` and `environmentID` is `RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTID` or `Release.EnvironmentId`, we could print them via `$(Release.ReleaseId)` and `$(Release.EnvironmentId)`

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you!  I wasn't looking at "classic" predefined variables page so couldn't find these.  Will test shortly and report back :-)